# How to access return value from a custom code activity?

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

I build a simple custom native activity that return a string value.

```
public sealed class MyActivity : NativeActivity<string>
{
     public InArgument<string> Id { get; set; }

     protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context)
     {
         var returnString = QuerySomthing();

         context.SetValue<string>(base.Result, returnString);
     }
}
```

How can I get this value in the workflow's variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the 'Result' property of your activity. All you need to do is create a variable on the workflow (of type String) and bind this to the 'Result' property. Then you can access the variable later on in the workflow to analyse its value. HTH

[image]